# Multithreaded tcp server accepting two clients with task factory and graceful shutdown

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking, tcp

as an exercise from multithreading and networking I have decided to create my own implementation of TCP server accepting connections from two clients (which is I think a pretty common case e.g. chess online games). The works as I wanted it to. Clients are connecting to server, messages from one client are passed to the other client and if server shutsdown or client decides to end the connection all application are shuting down. I would like to ask for code review in terms of code quality and performance. Is there anything I could do better?

TCP server implementation:

```
public sealed class TcpServer
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        var ipEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 12345);
        var tcpServer = new TcpListener(ipEndpoint);
    
        tcpServer.Start();
    
        Console.Write("Waiting for connections... ");
    
        var clientOne = await tcpServer.AcceptTcpClientAsync();            
        Console.WriteLine("Client one connected!\nWaiting for client two...");
        
        var clientTwo = await tcpServer.AcceptTcpClientAsync();            
        Console.WriteLine("Client two connected!");

        var taskFactory = new TaskFactory();
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token;
    
        var taskArray = new Task[3];
        taskArray[0] = taskFactory.StartNew(() => MessagingTask(clientOne, clientTwo, tokenSource, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
        taskArray[1] = taskFactory.StartNew(() => MessagingTask(clientTwo, clientOne, tokenSource, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
        taskArray[2] = taskFactory.StartNew(() => ServerConsole(tokenSource, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);

        Task.WaitAny(taskArray);
    }

    private static void ServerConsole(CancellationTokenSource tokenSource, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            while (Console.ReadLine() != "q")
            {
                
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Closing application...");
            tokenSource.Cancel();
        }
    }

    private static void MessagingTask(TcpClient clientOne, TcpClient clientTwo, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[256];
        var clientOneStream = clientOne.GetStream();
        var clientTwoStream = clientTwo.GetStream();

        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            int i;
            while ((i = clientOneStream.Read(bytes)) != 0)
            {
                var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: {data}");

                var msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                clientTwoStream.Write(msg);
            }

            if (i == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Client {clientOne.Client.LocalEndPoint} disconnected");
                tokenSource.Cancel();
            }
        }
    }
```

TCP client implementation:

```
public sealed class TcpClientTwo
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        var ipEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 12346);
        var tcpClient = new TcpClient(ipEndpoint);
    
        await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(ipAddress, 12345);
        
        var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    
        var taskFactory = new TaskFactory();
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token;
    
        var taskArray = new Task[3];
        taskArray[0] = taskFactory.StartNew(() => ReadingThread(tcpClient, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
        taskArray[1] = taskFactory.StartNew(() => SendingThread(tcpClient, tokenSource, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
        taskArray[2] = taskFactory.StartNew(() => ConnectionStatusThread(tcpClient, tokenSource, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
        
        Task.WaitAny(taskArray);

        stream.Close();
        tcpClient.Close();
    }

    private static void ConnectionStatusThread(TcpClient tcpClient, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (!tcpClient.Client.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server disconnected");
                tokenSource.Cancel();
            }

            Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
    
    private static void ReadingThread(TcpClient tcpClient, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[256];
        var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        while (true)
        {
            int i;
            while ((i = stream.Read(bytes)) != 0)
            {
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Server disconnected");
                    return;
                }

                var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: {data}");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void SendingThread(TcpClient tcpClient, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        string userInput = "";
        
        while (true)
        {
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();

            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server disconnected");
                return;
            }
            
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput))
                continue;

            if (userInput.Equals("q"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Closing application...");
                tokenSource.Cancel();
            }

            var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userInput);
            stream.Write(bytes);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this post let me focus only on the `TcpServer` class.
I will post another review about the `TcpClientTwo` class next week.

---

### `Main`

#### Waiting indefinitely for client

- Your `AcceptTcpClientAsync` can wait indefinitely
- If you want to avoid this situation then you have multiple options

##### .NET 6

- You can [pass a `CancellationToken`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclientasync?view=net-6.0#system-net-sockets-tcplistener-accepttcpclientasync(system-threading-cancellationtoken)) which was setup to timeout
- Please note that the overload which can accept a `CancellationToken` was introduced in .NET 6

  - [Related link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclientasync?view=net-6.0#system-net-sockets-tcplistener-accepttcpclientasync(system-threading-cancellationtoken)) (*Applies to* section)

```
var timeout = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
...
await tcpServer.AcceptTcpClientAsync(timeout.Token);
```

##### Prior .NET 6

- you can call `Stop` on the `TcpListener` in case of timeout

```
var timeout = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
timeout.Register(() => tcpServer.Stop());
```

- There are several SO topics which details the different options: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220957/tcplistener-how-to-stop-listening-while-awaiting-accepttcpclientasync), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524209/what-is-the-correct-way-to-cancel-an-async-operation-that-doesnt-accept-a-cance%5D%5B1%5D), etc.

#### `Task.Run` vs `Task.Factory.StartNew`

- Generally please prefer `Task.Run` over `Task.Factory.StartNew`

  - The former one does support `async` delegates while the latter doesn't
  - It is hard to define a `StartNew` in a correct way (using the good values for all of its parameters)
- Related SO topics: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423472/what-is-the-difference-between-task-run-and-task-factory-startnew), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693362/regarding-usage-of-task-start-task-run-and-task-factory-startnew), etc.
- Related Articles: [1](https://github.com/moljac/HolisticWare.WebSite.Notes/blob/master/dotnet-netfx/csharp/async-await/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew.1.md), [2](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), etc.
- In case of long-running jobs [prefer a dedicated `Thread` over `Task.Run`](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#avoid-using-taskrun-for-long-running-work-that-blocks-the-thread)

If your clients are connected for a couple of minutes (not hours) then `Task.Run` is fine

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task.WaitAny(new Task[]
{
    Task.Run(() => MessagingTask(clientOne, clientTwo, tokenSource)),
    Task.Run(() => MessagingTask(clientTwo, clientOne, tokenSource)),
    Task.Run(() => ServerConsole(tokenSource)),
});
```

- Since you are passing the `CancellationTokenSource` you don't need to pass the `CancellationToken` itself
- Also you don't have to pass the `CancellationToken` to the `Task.Run` because [it can only cancel those jobs which were not started yet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-task-run(system-action-system-threading-cancellationtoken)).

### `ServerConsole`

- I'm not really sure why do you need the outer while, since according to my understanding you will enter into the loop only once
- I would also suggest to accept capital `Q` as well
- From a naming perspective the method name should start with a verb, like `WaitForUserCancellation`, `ReadConsoleForUserCommands`, etc..

### `MessagingTask`

- It is a synchronous method, not an asynchronous one, so using `Task` as a suffix is misleading

  - IMHO a better name could be `TransferDataBetweenClients`, `HandleMessagingBetweenParties`, etc.
- Also calling parameters like `clientOne` and `clientTwo` are not really helpful

  - Calling them `sourceClient` and `targetClient` express your intent better
- Same applies to variable `i`, please prefer `readBytes`
- The `if (i == 0)` is pointless since that's your exit condition from the while loop

```
var buffer = new byte[256];
var sourceStream = sourceClient.GetStream();
var targetStream = targetClient.GetStream();

while (!tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    int readBytes;
    while ((readBytes = sourceStream.Read(buffer)) != 0)
    {
        var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, readBytes);
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: {message}");
        targetStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message));
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Client {sourceClient.Client.LocalEndPoint} disconnected");
    tokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

- Please bear in mind that 256 bytes for the buffer might not be enough

  - If you are sending a larger string then `Encoding.ASCII.GetString` won't be able to read the whole message

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you very for your feedback. I have already refactored my code so that it complies with your suggestions. I have mentioned you in my readme file. I hope you don't mind :) I am waiting impatiently for you review of the client implementation. In the meantime I have a question. I am reading a lot about async and await and even though I get an idea how they I still have this rookie lack of feeling when to use them. Is TransferDataBetweenClients a good use case for async await? Documentation classifies this method as I/O bound so answer would be yes but the code does it's job already

Comment: @Artur Hi, nice to meet you. It's an honour to be part of your readme :) Yes, [reading from a stream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.readasync?view=net-6.0) and [writing to another stream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.writeasync?view=net-6.0) can take advantage of the async I/O.

Answer (score 1):

In this post I'll focus on the other class (called `TcpClientTwo`).

---

### `TcpClientTwo`

- I know naming is hard. I know you can't name your class to `TcpClient` since it is a built-in class

  - I would suggest to try use some name which expresses your intent

    - like `DuplexClient`, `DialogueClient`, `WalkieTalkieClient`, etc.
  - After this renaming I would also encourage you to rename your `TcpServer`

### `Main`

- My advices here are more or less the same as in case of `TcpServer`'s `Main`
- Plus

  - You could rename this method to `StartAsync` to better express your intent
  - I would also suggest to receive the client port as a parameter rather than hard code it

    - Actually you should receive all your hard-coded values as parameters
  - `var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();`<< I'm not sure why do you need this line

    - If it is necessary to work correctly then I would suggest to add some comment here

### `ConnectionStatusThread`

- Yet again naming :)

  - This method is not using `Thread`s, so adding this as a suffix is misleading
  - I would suggest to name it like `CheckConnectionPeriodically`, `HandleDisconnectionAsync`, etc.
- The `Task.Delay` should be awaited otherwise it will not halt the execution
- I would suggest to reorganize your code to better express your intent

  - Until the client is connected and cancellation is not requested wait 1 seconds repeatedly
  - If client is disconnected then request cancellation

```
while (tcpClient.Client.Connected && !tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}

Console.WriteLine("Server disconnected");
if (!tcpClient.Client.Connected) tokenSource.Cancel();
```

### `ReadingThread`

- Suggested name: `ReadIncomingMessages`, `ReadMessagesFromPeer`, etc.
- I'm not really a huge fan of infinite loops, primarily because you (as a coder) have to read the whole loop body to understand the exit condition(s)
- In your case you do not need a nested infinitely loop

  - Why? Because your inner loop's condition is basically ignored

    - If you could not read anything then you restart the whole loop again due to the outer loop

```
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) 
{
    int readBytes = stream.Read(bytes);
    if (readBytes == 0)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        continue;
    }
    var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, readBytes);
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: {message}");
}

Console.WriteLine("Server disconnected"); //ambiguous
```

- I've added a small delay if you could not read anything from the stream
- I would like to also emphasize here that your console messages are ambiguous

  - You are emitting the exact same message from 3 different methods
  - I would suggest to revise your log messages

### `SendingThread`

- Suggested name: `SendUserInputs`, `SendMessagesToPeer`, etc.
- Same applies here for your infinite loop

  - It can be refactored so that the loop body will contain only that logic which should be repeated

```
do
{
    var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput)) continue;
    if (userInput.Equals("q")) break;

    var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userInput);
    stream.Write(bytes);

} while (!tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested);

if (tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Server disconnected"); //ambiguous
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Closing application...");
    tokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, again, for your magnificent code review :D I envy your skills. I am still wondering how could I have made so many obvious mistakes in terms of loop complexity. Also thank to your suggestion I have found that there is absolutely no need for CheckConnectionPeriodically task to exist. I have found out that this task did really not much after applying your suggestions. Instead I implemented try catch blocks in ReadIncomingMessages and SendUserInputs tasks. However I won't edit the first post. I think it is a better case study that way. It certainly was for me :D